# Chrome extension to save data to local file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, html5-filesystem

I'm making chrome extension, which will save every action in browser like new_tab, new_window, switch_tab, close_tab... But I want to store information locally in csv file. I tried many guides and tutorials, but still not working. 
For start I just want to save test string into local file, will be this file visible? I am planning getting this data from about 20 people.

In manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Getting started example",
  "description": "This is testing description",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Click here!"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    ]
}
```

In popup.html is imported javascript
`<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>`

and in popup.js is this:

```
window.onload = function() {
var filesystem = null;
window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;

window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 5*1024*1024 , onInitFs, errorHandler);

  function onInitFs() {
  filesystem = fs;

  filesystem.root.getFile('treehouse.txt', {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {

  fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {

  fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
   console.log("write done");
  };

  fileWriter.onerror = function(e) {
    console.log("write error");
  };

  var contentBlob = new Blob(['JUST OWN TEXT FOR TESTING!'], {type: 'text/plain'});

  fileWriter.write(contentBlob);

}, errorHandler);
}, errorHandler);

}


function errorHandler(e) {
  var msg = '';

  switch (e.message) {
    case FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR:
      msg = 'QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR';
      break;
    case FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
      msg = 'NOT_FOUND_ERR';
      break;
    case FileError.SECURITY_ERR:
      msg = 'SECURITY_ERR';
      break;
    case FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR:
      msg = 'INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR';
      break;
    case FileError.INVALID_STATE_ERR:
      msg = 'INVALID_STATE_ERR';
      break;
    default:
      msg = 'Unknown Error';
      break;
  };
  console.log('Error: ' + msg);
}
}
```

Giving error from console `Uncaught ReferenceError: fs is not defined` on line  `filesystem = fs;`
No file was created or I didnt find it. I assume root is somewhere C:/ or C:/Windows

Can anybody help with code repair? or some useful advice?

Comment: You don't appear to be assigning the `fs` variable anywhere, which is why it is null

Comment: thanks,,didnt see little mistake there.. due to this guide (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) fs is not assigned it is just parameter of function, so I make fs as a parameter of  onInitFs(fs) and console error dissapeared but I got 'Unknown Error' from errorHandler

Answer (score 0):

you need to change `onInitFs()` to `onInitFs(fs)` as the `window.requestFileSystem` function will pass you your new filesystem handle as an argument to the callback.